# Where is ssh daemon log file

Tags: linux, ssh, logging, centos5

I am facing a strange issue on my Centos 5.5 VMware virutal machine. SSHD service stops  responding after working for few days. At the same time `cmd>telnet server 22` give me no response. 
It works when I restart manually

```
service sshd restart
```

I want to identify what is going wrong with SSH daemon. For this I have changed the log verbosity to `DEBUG3` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, but I am unable to see any logs in `/var/log/messages`.

Can anyone help me to find the log file where I can see crash message whenever SSH daemon stops responding?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check:

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

Try to edit this options at sshd_config

```
# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH    # <- says to log auth.log, check syslog.conf for additional configuration, or even update remove syslog and install rsyslog.
#LogLevel INFO          # <- edit verbosity
```